# How To Redirect To Another Url Using JavaScript In MVC Page

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked before both on here and elsewhere, but everything I've tried and read is still failing for me.

I have (so far) tried the following inside a method I am successfully calling:

```
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.co.uk";
    window.location.replace = "http://www.google.co.uk";
    window.location = "http://www.google.co.uk";
    window.navigate = "http://www.google.co.uk";
    location.replace("http://www.google.co.uk");
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.co.uk");
    self.location = "http://www.google.co.uk";
    top.location = "http://www.google.co.uk";
    location.assign("http://www.google.co.uk");
```

This is inside a method I am calling from a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="SaveAndExit" onclick="saveAndExit();">GO TO GOOGLE</button>
```

This should be straightforward for something I've broken down so simple, but my screen just refreshes without navigating to the URL I specify.

What can't I see please?!

Comment: Try with setting `type="button"` of button, apart from that it should work

Comment: Is this button in a form that's being submitted?  When you debug this, what is actually happening?  Is the redirect line of code being reached?  What network requests are being made?

Comment: for better testing please use console.log('Go') before `    window.location.href = "http://www.google.co.uk";` . I think your code not reaching this line.

Comment: Thanks Satpal, that was what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default type of a HTML `button` is `submit`, in this case `onclick` does not run, use

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="saveAndExit" onclick="saveAndExit()">
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have an `<input type="button">` instead of a `button` component.

So your button should look like:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="SaveAndExit" onclick="saveAndExit();">GO TO GOOGLE</button>
```